# Sqlite reduce size

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have a SQLITE database.
I use System.Data.Sqlite

I have the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE [DYN_record_player] (
  [id_player] INT NOT NULL, 
  [tournament] SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
  [tournament_phase] TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
  [type_record] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
  [value] SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
  [player_team] INT, 
  [versus_team] INT, 
  [date] INT, 
  CONSTRAINT [sqlite_autoindex_DYN_record_player_1] PRIMARY KEY ([id_player], [tournament], [tournament_phase], [type_record]));

CREATE INDEX [rec.joueur] ON [DYN_record_joueur] ([id_joueur]);
```

When the user uses my application it fills the database (from 20k lines at the beginning to ~1 million) :
Every tournament is divided in 2/3/4 phase per player and for each phase he has 10 types of record which have a value.

```
tournament_phase is always < 10
type_value is always < 100
tournament is always < 1000
```

As you can imagine this increase the database's file (from 10mo to 80, it's not only this table but mainly).

How can I reduce the size taken by each row ?

I didn't find any answer, every topic is talking about VACUUM. Yeah I use Vacuum but that's not the point, my database is 80mo after using VACUUM.

Comment: 80mb is not that bad, unless you are talking about a mobile application, why does your app need a million rows? Are you caching data from other users?

Comment: Please note that SQLite ignores the column types and automatically [uses the smalles encoding for numbers](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format). There's nothing you can do, except reducing the number of columns.

Comment: Oh, I thought maybe I had a structure issue, the table could be improved using binary encoding or something.